# Promise.all() - Do something after multiple event listeners are triggered

Tags: javascript, events, asynchronous, promise

I am using a cartographic API that implement a `layer` object. There is an event on the layer that is fired when the layer's `features` finished loading. This process is asynchronous.

I want to use Promise to handle the moment when features of each map's layers are loaded. However sometimes layer's features are already loaded before I have added the listener and sometimes not.

I am trying to use `Promise.all()` like below, but I am not sure if its the best way to achieve what I am trying to do.

```
var layers = [layer1, layer2, layer3];
var promises = [];

Promise.all(promises).then(function() {
    //here am I sure that all layers features are loaded?
    doSomething();
});

layers.forEach(function(layer) {
   if (layer.features.length > 0) {
      //features are already loaded 
      onFeaturesLoaded();
   } else {
      //features not loaded yet, a one time event listener is added 
      layer.addOneTimeEventListener(layer.EVENTS.FEATURES_LOADED, onFeaturesLoaded, layer);
   }
});

function onFeaturesLoaded() {
   return new Promise(function(resolve) {
       resolve();
   });
};
```

Comment: It seems fine to me. I have written code like this many times and have never had an issue. The only thing to be careful of (and I don't know your API so I can't say if this is a problem) is what if something goes wrong? Is there an error event where you can reject the promise? Right now if `FEATURES_LOADED` never fired for some reason your code will just hang. You don't have any way to alert the user of an error. But perhaps this is handled elsewhere in your code. Just something to be mindful of.

Comment: Actually I lied, at the time you are calling `Promise.all` the promises array is empty. You'll need to create your promises ahead of time then rather than doing `new Promise` in your event handler, resolve the correct promise from the array. Right now I suspect this would return immediately. Your concept is fine, it just needs to be refined to make sure you're actually waiting on the promises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems like a perfectly valid use of `Promise.all`.

One thing to note: your `forEach` loop will need to return promises in the `addEventListener` case so `Promise.all` can operate on them.

Using `map()` might be a little bit easier for you as you'll have a nice Array to pass right into `Promise.all`.

```
Promise.all(layers.map(function(layer){ 
    if(layer.features.length === 0){
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            layer.addEventListener(layer.EVENTS.FEATURES_LOADED, function(){ resolve(); }, layer);
        });
    }
    else{
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){ resolve(); });
    }
})
.then(function(){ 
    // Everything is loaded at this point.
});
```

That will give you an array of promises for layers that have yet to load and promises that resolve immediately for those already loaded.

Comment: Note, this looks like it adds an event listener each time it is run and that is never removed.  If this is called more than once, those event listeners will pile up.

Comment: @jfriend00 you are right, but I am using a special addOneTimeEventListener function that automatically remove the listener after being fired

Comment: `return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){ resolve(); });` seems identical to `Promise.resolve()`.

Comment: @BelowtheRadar - You may be using `addOneTimeEventListener()`, but this answer is not.  My comment was about this answer.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly modified and DRYer answer based on @ajm's solution:

```
Promise.all(layers.map(function(layer){ 
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        if(layer.features.length === 0) {
            layer.addOneTimeEventListener(layer.EVENTS.FEATURES_LOADED, function(){ resolve(); }, layer);
        } else {
            resolve();
        }
    });
}))
.then(function(){ 
    // Everything is loaded at this point.
});
```